# android add tabs to Frame Layoutdynamic

Tags: android, android-tabhost

I want to add a new TabWidget / Tabhost to a FrameLayout dynamiclly on runtime. I dont want to use any layout.xml

That means on runtime a User click on a button and the TabHost should be added to a FrameBorder on Runtime.

I allways get
E/AndroidRuntime(925): java.lang.RuntimeException: Your TabHost must have a TabWidget whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.tabs'

Has anyone an idea to add the TabHost without defining it in the layout.xml?

I Used this code:

```
        TabHost tabHost = new TabHost(this);
    tabHost.setup();

    TabHost tabHost = new TabHost(this);
    tabHost.setup();

    TabSpec tab1 = tabHost.newTabSpec("ss");
    TabSpec tab2 = tabHost.newTabSpec("k");

    tab1.setIndicator("First");
    tab1.setContent(this);

    tab2.setIndicator("second");
    tab2.setContent(this);
    tabHost.addTab(tab1);
    tabHost.addTab(tab2);
    FrameLayout fl = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.kontakteDetailFrameLayout);
    fl.removeAllViews();
```

fl.addView(tabHost);

Comment: the error is not self explaining?

Comment: The Problem is that i dont want to use the xml-File which would contain android.R.id.tabs.There must be a way to do this without XML

Comment: and it is. just addView() a TabWidget with given id so that setup() method will run with no errors, see http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/1.6_r2/android/widget/TabHost.java line 100